# Undefined subroutine error using WWW::Curl::Form in Perl

Tags: perl, curl

I have this error in my script, but everything seems to be in order:

Undefined subroutine &WWW::Curl::Form::curl_formaddfile caclled at /home/script.pm line 107

lines around 107 line looks like this:

```
my $curlf = WWW::Curl::Form->new;

$curlf->curl_formaddfile($nfo, 'nfo', "multipart/form-data"); #107 line
$curlf->curl_formaddfile($torrent, 'file', "multipart/form-data");
$curlf->curl_formadd("name", $name);
$curlf->curl_formadd("type", $category);
$curlf->curl_formadd("descr", $$descr_txt);
$curlf->curl_formadd("anonymous", "1");
$curlf->curl_formadd("samehash", "1");

my $curl = new WWW::Curl::Easy;
my $response_details;
# windows check
if($os eq "windows"){
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, \&curl_write_data); 
}else{
    open (my $response_details_raw, ">", \$response_details);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,$response_details_raw);
}
my @curl_headers=('Expect:');
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, \@curl_headers);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie_glabella);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_REFERER, $upload_referer);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, $curlf);
```

$nfo prints out as /home/file.nfo

after that goes WWW::Curl::Easy and it does not work as it can not POST from this data.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the [doc](http://search.cpan.org/~szbalint/WWW-Curl-4.15/lib/WWW/Curl.pm#WWW%3a%3aCurl%3a%3aForm), the method `curl_formaddfile` is listed in the `Compatibility` section (`Seems to be working.`). 
Maybe you have a newer module so you should use the method `formaddfile` instead

See below an example from the doc:

```
    use WWW::Curl::Form;
    my $curlf = WWW::Curl::Form->new;
    $curlf->formaddfile($filename, 'attachment', "multipart/form-data");
    $curlf->formadd("FIELDNAME", "VALUE");

    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, $curlf);
```

Comment: The problem is my script is totally like that. I do not understand much of PERL, but I checked it from every side and cpould not find the problem. My code continues just like in your example. I updated my post so you could see it`s the same.

Comment: You are not using the `formaddfile` method. Change from `curl_formaddfile` to `formaddfile`